# Problem accessing EVLR slot in LASheader with lidR version 3.1.2

Tags: r, lidr

I'm using `lidR 3.1.2`. This problem has been occurring since very recently with the following error

```
Error in eval(call("@", object, slot)) : 
  no slot of name "EVLR" for this object of class "LASheader"`
```

The error occurs when I try to view the header, or with `writeLAS()`.

On another computer that initially had version `3.1.1`, there was no problem dealing with the exact same `.Rdata` containing the object. I updated it to `3.1.2` and the error occurred there as well.

The `.Rdata` file was created earlier containing an object which is a list of point cloud subsets. The subsets were created using lidR functions.

Furthermore, I reinstalled the previous version and there was no problem viewing the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `lidR` 3.1.2 the class `LASheader` has a new slot `@EVLR` to be compatible with `rlas 1.4.0` which bring a better support of LAS formats (especially 1.4) by allowing (among other) to read and write `Extended Variable Length Records`. This change is expected to be backward compatible so you should not have a problem but you loaded an already existing R object saved in a `.rds` or `.Rdata` file which is not longer in a compatible format.

To fix it, read your LAS file again with `readLAS()`. If, for a reason or another, you can't read again the file you should be able to init `@EVLR` manually then save back the `.Rdata`. I tested it:

```r
# with 3.1.1
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile)
saveRDS(las, "Megaplot.rds")

# with 3.1.2
las <- readRDS("Megaplot.rds")
las@header # broken
las@header@EVLR <- list()
las@header # fixed
```